# Retrieve json object value from input text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is json data--> `[{"id":"15aea3fa","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}]`.

How to get just `id` using javascript.

Comment: var textInput =  document.getElementById('textInput')
var json = JSON.parse(textInput.value)
// json[0].id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the text box value to `JSON` format from `Plain text`,

```
// getting value from textbox
var data = document.getElementById('youtextBoxId').value;

// data = [{"id":"15aea3fa","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}]

// convert it to json format
data = JSON.parse(data);

// getting Id of first data
alert(data[0]['id']); //15aea3fa
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function parseJSON() {
  var textInput = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

  if (textInput !== '') {
    try {
      let json = JSON.parse(textInput);
      console.log(json[0].id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="button" onClick="parseJSON()" value="extractID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access id using below code:

```
data[0].id
```